# Prevent page from freezing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating an html page and it contains `n` number of script files.

In my html page on the `window.onload`I'm` calling one of my functions as

```
<script>
 window.onload = function () {
        MyMethod('Value');
    };
</script>
```

When it hits this part of code my page is getting freezed until the execution of the function is completed.

The reason I have said n number of scripts is because this problem never exists with the other script files but for this particular window.onload call.

How can I make from getting stuck when the function called

**MyMethod** takes the value makes an `ajax` call to one of my service,based on the `result` either it `displays` or `hides` some of my elements

**JavaScript**

```
function MyMethod(val) {
var par = val;
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/services/MyService/MethodName",
            data: par,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                arr = response.d.toString().split(',');
                 if (arr[0] == "0") {
                    //show and hide some DOM elements 
                 }
                else{
                    //show and hide other DOM elements 
                 }
            },
            error: function (response) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: what is `MyMethod` doing? Without seeing it we can only guess what causes the lock up.

Comment: It will get stuck, fire a timer, and put your method in that timer.

Comment: @Gar A timer would just delay the freezing code

Comment: So is this ajax call synchronous??? What retuns this ajax call? Anything updating DOM?  Again, post relevant code regarding what you are doing inside MyMethod, otherwise we can just guessing...

Comment: You have to understand, the more 'you ask to' the DOM, the more it freezes the UI...  Now surely your code to hide/show elements(how many???) could be optimized

Comment: Does your page freeze when you comment out your function call? i.e. `//MyMethod('value');`

Comment: It is the service that takes time to respond. Make sure MyMethod is async, and it won't freeze. Also, post the code for MyMethod function, as that is the one with problem. This call is fine as is.

Comment: Firstly then, remove `async: false,`...

Comment: I knew the DOM manipulation takes time, is there anything I can do counter that

Comment: Where are you executing this script in your DOM? inside `head`?

Comment: @Wolff I did what you said but it is giving some unexpecting results

Comment: @AjayA : a timer of 100ms , it is going to delay a bit but gives a chance to the page to load.

Answer (score 0):

Make `async` `true`.

```
async: true,
```

Comment: I cannot make async: true, because I have some other logic to implement